# CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession") returns error code 800401FA

Tags: vbscript, outlook-redemption

I'm trying to use the redemption library in my script now and I can't load it.

```
Set m_objRDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
```

I have also tried to load it directly like the following

```
Set m_objRDOSession = GetObject("Redemption.dll", "Redemption.RDOSession")
```

Both the same error code, with null message and source.

I'm using windows 64 bit with outlook 32 bit. I have successfully loaded the library with c# and the redemption loader on the same machine.

PS: I should mention that I saw the terms and agreement prompt before the error got thrown.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code `0x800401FA` is `CO_E_WRONGOSFORAPP`.

If the machine is 64 bit, you will end up using the 64 bit version of cscript.exe, but the bitness of your code must match the bitness of Outlook - use cscript.exe from the SysWow64 folder.

Extended MAPI is a set of dlls loaded in-proc, and a 64 bit process cannot load a 32 bit dll and vice versa.

See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register the DLL to the machine?

Using **CreateObject** must have the COM object in the local registry.

In C# you can load the library without registering it using the RedemptionLoader class, but this method can not be used in VBScript.

Comment: If I use CreateObject with a path to the dll, is it possible to use without registering?