# Converting Outlook code from VBScript to C#

Tags: c#, vbscript

I am trying to write equivalent code in C# for the following code.

```vb
Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession") 
objNS.Logon "appsystemacc", "App@12345", False, False
objNS.MAPIOBJECT = objApp.Session.MAPIOBJECT

EntryID = "someValue"
StoreID = "someValue2"
Set olFolder = objNS.GetFolderFromID(EntryID,StoreID)
```

So far, I have converted to the following code, but it gives me "Operation failed" error on debugging in the `GetFolderFromID()` line:

```cs
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
oNS.Logon("appsystemacc", "App@12345", false, false);

var EntryID = "someValue";
var StoreID = "someValue2";

var folderID = oNS.GetFolderFromID(EntryID, StoreID);
```

I also wanted to know why is `Redemption.RDOSession`is used ? Is it used to get all email types from Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop on the collection of the folders and find the requested folder, here is a way to do that. please read comments inside the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
namespace outlook
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
            oNS.Logon("appsystemacc", "App@12345", false, false);

            // THE FOLDER YOU WISH TO FIND
            Outlook.MAPIFolder MySomeValueFolder = null;
            // USE THIS TO INDICATE IF FOUND
            bool IsFound = false;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Folders oFolders;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oPublicFolder =
                oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent;
            // Folders at Inbox level
            oFolders = oPublicFolder.Folders;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder Folder in oFolders)
            {
                // OPTIONAL:
                // if(Folder.Name == "somevalue") { ... }
                if (Folder.EntryID == "someValue")
                {
                    Console.Write(Folder.Name + " " + Folder.StoreID);
                    MySomeValueFolder = Folder;
                    IsFound = true;
                }     
            }

            if (IsFound)
            {
                // now do with MySomeValueFolder whatever you want
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question - there is no code equivalent for `Set objNS = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")` in C# ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18600645/5718868: Using CreateObject must have the COM object in the local registry.
In C# you can load the library without registering it using the RedemptionLoader class, but this method can not be used in VBScript. another thing about syntax `set x = CreateObject('MyObject')`  can be equivalent to `MyObject x = new MyObject()` in c#. this is how you set an instance of an object..

Comment: So you are saying C# code `Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi")` replacement for `Set objNS = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")` is fine ?

Comment: I tried `Redemption.RDOSession RDSession = (Redemption.RDOSession)new Redemption.RDOSession();`; but it gives me missing namespace error.

Comment: @KanuPriya you already created an instance of the namespace: `Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");` use oNS properties if you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace

Comment: Is there any other way to take values of  `EntryID` and `StoreID` ? I think that's why the answer is downvoted.

Comment: @KanuPriya, please read my updated answer. is that what you need?

Comment: Using your previous code `Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox`, it should directly take inbox mail items, right ?